# Could anyone please help me identify/translate this mantra?

Tags: tibetan-buddhism, mantra, tibetan

It appears at the top of two different thangkas in a gompa, one representing Sakyamuni and another one with Vajrasattva in yab yum, and I am unable to find what it means.please help me clarify what mantra is that?

[image]

Comment: I had no luck trying to identify this with OCR, but the second and fourth character on the bottom row (from the left) look like Punjabi, not Tibetan.

Answer (score 1):

This is Lantsa script.

The top character is *hrīḥ*

The mantra reads: *oṃ ma ṇi pa dme hūṃ*

i.e. *oṃ maṇipadme hūm* the mantra of Avalokiteśavara. Note that contra popular opinion, *maṇīpadme* is one word. And the *-e* ending is a Prakrit nominative singular, not a Sanskrit locative singular or whatever.

For more on this mantra see: https://www.visiblemantra.org/avalokitesvara.html